# Yet another Classpath java

Tags: java, jar, classpath, javac

Hello ive some trouble with CLASSPATh and compiling in Java.

I have this test code:

```
package prova;
import cat.almata.daw.utils.Log;

public class ProvaUtils {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            System.out.println("------ Testing DAW Utils ---");

            System.out.println("--- Testing Log class ---"); 
            Log logTest = new Log("logTest.log");

            System.out.println("Going to write an Info");
            logTest.info("Some information to write in the log");

            System.out.println("Going to write a Warning");
            logTest.warning("Some warning to write in the log");

            System.out.println("Going to write an Error");
            logTest.error("Some error to write in the log");
            System.out.println("Hola Mon");


        }catch(Exception e){
            //System.out.println("An Exception has been thrown, with message:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

So i got a DAWUtils.jar which has inside the .class of Log. If you uncompress that jar you got the path cat -> almata -> daw -> utils -> Log.class.

So i need Log.class to execute my test code.

My folder:

```
practicaJava/
├── DAWUtils.jar
├── MANIFEST.MF
├── prova
│   ├── ProvaUtils.java
```

When i want to compile and execute ( using Jar):

```
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~/Descargas/practicaJava$ javac -classpath "/home/eduardo/Descargas/practicaJava/DAWUtils.jar" ./prova/ProvaUtils.java
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~/Descargas/practicaJava$ java prova.ProvaUtils ------ Testing DAW Utils ---
--- Testing Log class ---
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cat/almata/daw/utils/Log
    at prova.ProvaUtils.main(ProvaUtils.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cat.almata.daw.utils.Log
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

It works ok if in that same folder i uncompress the jar;

$jar xvf DAWUtils.jar

And having:

eduardo@MiPcLinux:~/Descargas$ tree practicaJava/

```
practicaJava/
├── cat
│   └── almata
│       └── daw
│           └── utils
│               └── Log.class
├── DAWUtils.jar
├── MANIFEST.MF
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
└── prova
       └── ProvaUtils.java
```

Im running all the instructions from my folder practicaJava. So it shouldnt work that way, i think that if i have the jar file it has to get the Log.class and work without needing to uncompress it. So Log.class i have it uncompress and inside DAWUtils.jar

I also need to make a jar ( including the .jar in the MAnifest.mf) and it doesnt work for the same reason:

$jar cvfm ProvaUtils.jar MANIFEST.MF prova/ DAWUtils.jar

With Manifest.mf:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.5.0_06 (BEA Systems, Inc.)
Main-Class: prova.ProvaUtils
Class-Path: /home/eduardo/Descargas/practicaJava/DAWUtils.jar
```

It seems i need to have the DAWUtils.jar uncompress to work.As you can see im in Ubuntu Linux.

Any help would be apreciated.

As requested by:

```
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~/Descargas/practicaJava$ javac -classpath "/home/eduardo/Descargas/practicaJava/prova/DAWUtils.jar" ./prova/ProvaUtils.java 
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~/Descargas/practicaJava$ java prova.ProvaUtils ------ Testing DAW Utils ---
--- Testing Log class ---
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cat/almata/daw/utils/Log
    at prova.ProvaUtils.main(ProvaUtils.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cat.almata.daw.utils.Log
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to specify the same classpath at runtime. Are you using an IDE? It will sort all of this out for you.

Comment: You should use the same classpath for both the `javac` and the `java`.

Comment: @Michael Certainly you can use a JAR name in a CLASSPATH. For about 15 years that was the only way to get a JAR into a CLASSPATH.

Comment: No i cant use an IDE. Its a practice and i have to use the jar in the classpath in command line. Thanks

Comment: @EJP Fair enough. Edited my comment then.

Comment: @RealSkeptic it doesnt work either....if i dont have the jar uncompress i got the error:  --- Testing Log class ---
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cat/almata/daw/utils/Log

Comment: [edit] your question and add the exact command line you used for `java` with the classpath, and the error. Never put code or errors in comments.

Comment: Done its put on "requested by" at the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to refer to the DAWUtils.jar with .:DAWUtils.jar

So:
$ javac -classpath .:DAWUtils.jar ./prova/ProvaUtils.java

Works and then:

$ java -classpath .:DAWUtils.jar prova.ProvaUtils

To execute.

Comment: An answer should not be used to ask follow-up questions. Create a new question.